# VBA OnKey And Pass a Variable

Tags: excel, vba, variables, key

I am trying to have an OnKey event trigger a sub and pass a variable to that sub. Triggering the sub with a button works just fine (these are both in Module1):

```
Sub button77()
scanner (1)
End Sub

Sub scanner(keyscan As Integer)
Debug.Print keyscan
End Sub
```

What also works is triggering the sub without a variable (first part is on a worksheet, the second is still in Module1):

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()
Application.OnKey "1", "scanner"
End Sub

Sub scanner()
Debug.Print "TEST"
End Sub
```

But I cannot get the following to work:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()
Application.OnKey "1", "scanner(1)"
End Sub

Sub scanner(keyscan As Integer)
Debug.Print keyscan
End Sub
```

It gives me "Argument not Optional". I've tried to format the procedure of OnKey to various iterations - for example

```
Application.OnKey "1", "'scanner" & 1 & "'"
```

and others, tried with a string but it does not work no matter what I try. Anyone knows what is going on?

Comment: You're missing a space before the argument: `Application.OnKey "1", "'scanner " & 1 & "'"`

Comment: Thanks - immediately works. Appreciated! offtopic but is it custom to 'resolve' a question on stackoverflow? I do not see any way to do this.

Comment: I can post that as an answer that you can accept.

Comment: resolved - thanks again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing a space before the argument:

```
Application.OnKey "1", "'scanner " & 1 & "'"
```

so that it reads as 'scanner 1' not 'scanner1' which would make the code look for a routine called `scanner1`.